# Help! How do you s/// "[one] abc [two]" into "X abc X"?

Tags: regex, sed

My failed attempt:

```
s/\[[^\[\]]*\]/X/
```

No match in ed or sed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the literal string [one] abc [two] use e.g. this:

```
s/[[][^]]*]/X/g
```

It'll replace `[` + `anything not ]` + `]` with X.

Comment: You're faster than me @Erik! Also : `s/\[[^]]*\]/X/g` works with sed

Comment: I guess you understood better than me. :)

Comment: `[[]` or `\[` matches `[`, `\]` or just `]` matches `]`

Answer (score 0):

The [brackets] literally? Or is the blank the significant part?

```
sed -r 's/(.*) (.*) (.*)/X \2 X/'

echo "[one] abc [two]" | sed -r 's/(.*) (.*) (.*)/X \2 X/'
X abc X
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ echo "[one] abc [two]" | ruby -e 'print gets.gsub(/\[.*?\]/,"X") '
X abc X
```